# Passing Parameters From Page-to-page

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, parameters

I have a filter that is used to populate a grid view and the url will conain: /example/grid?value1=1&value2=2

It will then have a link to page 2, which allows them to edit something.

I then want them to click a link that will send them back to the gridview under the same parameters of: /example/grid?value1=1&value2=2

Is this possible?  How do I hold on and fill in the URL values so it knows how to refill the grid view accordingly??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Well since you're using MVC, you should add parameters to your Grid controller that allow you to pass in parameters, then the url would look like this:

`/example/grid/1/2`

Then in your code you just need to read the parameters while you're filling the grid and apply the appropriate logic.